# Less of something (British English Probably)

Tags: expressions

- Less of this noise, guys!
- Less of that funny talk!
- Less of talking nonsense!
- Less of working late!

---

Does it mean less or stop doing something?

Comment: it means less but is synonym to "tone it down" which is almost a command to stop it

Comment: "Less"="not more" --> Less of something = (Let's have) no more of it. Haha.

Comment: Note that you use *of* only when the noun is preceded by a *determiner*. "Less [Ø] talking nonsense", but "Less **of your/that/this** talking nonsense" ... "Less [Ø] funny talk", but "Less **of that** funny talk".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The imperative expression "less of ..." means both less and stop.

It is a form much loved of school teachers to mean "If you are unable to moderate the behaviour that you know is not permitted, then I will be required to take direct action to stop it entirely. We share the implicit understanding that I do not wish to take that action, but I will if necessary".

Failure to respond to the original instruction can lead to the equally incomprehensible "All right. I warned you. Cut it out."

Comment: +1 Followed by the even less comprehensible "That does it, Harris, drop and gimme ten".